# Как скомпилировать приложение киви в apk?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, kivy, apk

у меня такая проблема:Сижу на Windows 7 32-bit.Сделал приложение на Киви,начал искать способы компиляции в apk.Там нужен либо Линукс либо Virtual box или Ubuntu.Как известно все они под 64 бит.Есть ли решение моей проблемы или лучше учить PYQT и как в нем компилировать apk.

Comment: Я бы на твоём месте переполз на 64. Потому что те, костыли которые ты хочешь сделать сейчас - будут аукаться после в самых неожиданных местах.

Comment: процессор и ос  новые?

Comment: подскажи сайт с виндой 7 64бит  про

Comment: `sha1` оригинального win7-64-sp1-ru скачанного с MSDN: `6aafbbffc12bb63894932210d5bcb69773b46c98`. Дальше сам. Откуда качать - значения не имеет, если хэш будет совпадать. Но лучше с рутрекера, там и активаторы обычно нормальные лежат.

Comment: Win можно скачать с сайта MS, а остальное думаю сами справитесь ))

Comment: @Kers, о, а можно пошагово описать где на сайте microsoft.com лежит оригинальный образ win7? С прямой ссылкой конечно же. Без всяких "зайди в личный кабинет, который тебе предоставил официальный реселлер".

Comment: @don Rumata хм.. там сейчас правда требует серийник. Если есть какой-нибудь то https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows7 и если вдруг то для 10 без лишних замарочек https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows10

Comment: Откуда классического русскоязычного пользователя серийник от win7 pro? Я же написал: "без энтерпрайзных уловок".

Answer (score 0):

Этот сайт может помочь:

```
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/kaustubhgupta/0d06ea84760f65888a2488bac9922c25/kivyapp-to-apk.ipynb#scrollTo=wyVLXEgJFeqv
```

Из минусов: оставляет хлам на гугл диске, возможно, будет медленнее, чем на linux.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]